# Defining the critical point of an elementary embedding when there exist incomparable cardinals.

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Assume one has. for $V$ and for some transitive class $M$, an elementary embedding

$j$: $V$$\rightarrow$$M$ and that $j$$\neq$$id$, where $id$ is the identity.

If $V$ and $M$ satisfy $ZFC$ then the following Theorem holds

Thm.  Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal.

(i) For every $\alpha$, $j$($\alpha$)$\ge$$\alpha$

(ii) $j$ moves some ordinal.

Let $\delta$ be the least ordinal moved by $j$.  $\delta$ is called the critical point of $j$.

It can be proven in $ZFC$ that $\delta$ is always a cardinal.

Suppose now that $j$: $V$$\rightarrow$$M$, and $V$ and $M$ both satisfy $ZF$+$\lnot$$AC$.  How can the critical point $\delta$ be defined when there exist incomparable cardinals?

I hope that this is not too silly a question.  If it turns out to be silly, I will happily delete it.

(Addendum:  Regarding Noah's answer to my question ("...even though the cardinalities of $V$ may not be well-ordered, the cardinals and ordinals definitely will be..."), in $ZF$+$\lnot$$AC$, there are cardinals which are not ordinals, and these may not be comparable.  Since under a nontrivial elementary embedding no ordinal would be moved, could such cardinals be critical points of such an embedding?)

Comment: $\delta$ is in that case defined as the least ordinal moved by $j$.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo:  Regardless of whether or not there incomparable cardinals?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Why does the usual definition seem unsatisfactory if choice fails?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I am trying to get at the reason(s) (perhaps too indirectly--I really should come out and ask...) why it is so difficult to prove whether $ZF$ admits Reinhardt cardinals or not.  I guess I have difficulty picturing what a $V$ satisfying $ZF$+$\lnot$$AC$ 'looks like' (if in fact one can actually picture such a thing...)

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Why not ask that then? I'd certainly be interested in the answer. All I really know is why the standard proof doesn't work without choice (see page 82 of http://math.bu.edu/people/aki/d.pdf for a beautifully short proof, the most understandable I've seen), and the fact that I can't think of how to fix it. :P

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  Should I use the 'open-question' tag if I should ask it on Mathoverflow?

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  By the way, why doesn't the standard proof work without $AC$?  It would seem that if you knew that,  the answer on how to fix it or whether it can be fixed should be forthcoming.... Of course, if the standard proof cannot be fixed in $ZF$+$\lnot$$AC$ (or better, in $NGB$+$\lnot$AC), would that imply the existence of a nontrivial  elementary embedding $j$:$V$$\rightarrow$$V$?

Comment: By "the proof can't be fixed," I just mean: "the proof uses AC at a point, in an essential way, so that any proof of the inconsistency of Reinhardts with ZF will need to be fundamentally different." Of course I can't *prove* that the proof can't be fixed in the non-AC context :D. The point where AC is used is in constructing an $\omega$-Jonsson function on $\lambda=\sup\{j^n(\kappa): n\in\omega\}$; read the proof and you'll see what's going on.

Comment: I think the open question tag would be appropriate, yes. But I'd be careful to phrase the question precisely, so that it's actually answerable - think about what you would consider a satisfying explanation of why it's hard to prove that Reinhardts are inconsistent with ZF.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Re: your recent edit, I think that you misunderstood my answer: by "cardinal" I mean "ordinal not in bijection with any smaller ordinal," that is, "well-orderable cardinality" (or $\aleph$-number, per Asaf). As I said in my answer, if $j$ fixes all the $\aleph$-numbers, then $j$ is the identity. Non-well-orderable cardinalities just aren't relevant.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  In that case, can't it be said that $AC$ holds 'locally', i.e. for that particular class?  If so, then the Kunen inconsistency seemingly never fails....

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin For the class of well-orderable sets? Yes, AC definitely holds for this class . . . I'm not sure what this has to do with Kunen.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  If I am understanding you correctly, you are saying that only well-orderable cardinalities are relevant when considering nontrivial elementary embeddings from $V$$\rightarrow$$M$ , where $V$ and $M$ both satisfy $ZF$+$\lnot$$AC$.  Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd go that far; just that, if we define the critical point as the least ordinal moved by $j$, then this exists iff $j$ is nontrivial. My point is merely that, *as far as your question goes*, non-well-orderable sets have no impact on what the critical point means, or its basic properties.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  Thanks for your explanation.  It's very helpful.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  By the way, couldn't a non-well-orderable cardinal be moved by a nontrivial elementary embedding $j$?

Comment: Sure, but I don't see how that's relevant. If $j$ is a nontirvial elementary embedding (and either $V$ is well-founded or $j$ is definable), then there is a least ordinal moved by $j$, and this seems to be the only appropriate thing to call the "critical point."

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  But that seems to require that every cardinal is in 1-1 correspondence to an ordinal, which does not happen in  models of $ZF$+$\lnot$$AC$.  Can't non-ordinal cardinals be 'large' large cardinals? And if so, what happens to the notion of elementary embedding?

Comment: Ah, I think I see your confusion. Suppose there is an $X$-complete ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on a set $X$, and moreover that $X$ is not well-orderable. This can happen. Now, I'm guessing you want to argue, form the usual elementary embedding $j: V\rightarrow M$ where $M$ is the Mostowski collapse of the ultrapower $\prod_X V/\mathcal{U}$. Then isn't $X$ the "critical point"? (cont'd)

Comment: The answer is no, for a couple reasons. First, $\prod_X V/\mathcal{U}$ might not be well-founded at all! For instance, take $X$ amorphous and let $\mathcal{U}$ be the ultrafilter of cofinite subsets of $X$. In order to argue $\prod_X V/\mathcal{U}$ is well-founded, we need countable choice. But suppose we grant that. Then we *do* get an embedding $V\rightarrow M$. But the role of $X$ in this embedding is completely unclear! (cont'd)

Comment: In particular, let's look at the natural assertion at this stage: "$X$ is a minimal moved cardinality." That is, if $Y\subset X$ is of strictly smaller cardinality, then $j(Y)=Y$. Is this true? The usual proof uses the fact that the union of fewer-than-$X$-many sets of size smaller-than-$X$ has size smaller than $X$ (if $X$ admits an $X$-complete ultrafilter in the first place); however, it's not clear to me that this is true in the choice-free context. Moreover, even so, the least (von Neumann) ordinal moved by $j$ still exists and is interesting - and that's the critical point.

Comment: But you should note that the argument "If $j$ is nontrivial (and definable, or $V$ is well-founded), it moves some ordinal" is true in ZF alone, and doesn't require choice. The crucial axiom, actually, is **foundation** - the point is that if $j\upharpoonright\alpha=id\upharpoonright\alpha$ for some ordinal $\alpha$, then (by transfinite induction) $j$ is the identity on $V_\alpha$, so for $j$ to move anything (since $\bigcup_{\alpha\in ON} V_\alpha=V$) it has to move an ordinal "first."

Comment: Actually, looking a couple comments back, it's not at all clear that the map $V\rightarrow M$ we get is even elementary! (Los' theorem needs choice . . .)

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  All of your comments are very, very helpful.  Regarding your last comment, are you saying that the map $V$$\rightarrow$$M$ where $V$ and $M$ both satisfy $ZF$+$\lnot$$AC$ may be an embedding, but not elementary?

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the case. But it's worse than that - I don't even see that $M\models ZF$!

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  Are you possibly saying $M$$\vDash$$ZF^{-f}$?

Comment: No, $M$ will satisfy foundation (at least, if we assume $V$ is well-founded :P), it's the other big axioms I'm worried about: why should $M$ satisfy replacement or separation? Los' theorem requires some choice. But I think this is a good mathoverflow question, rather than something to be hashed out in the comments; do you mind if I ask it, or would you prefer to?

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  I think I will let you ask the question since I think you have a better handle on it than I.  Paul Corazza  has been able to define a nontrivial elementary embedding $V$$\rightarrow$$V$ not satisfying replacement and the size of this cardinal is just below I3.  As for separation--I don't know.  Can you show that $M$$\vDash$$ZF-Separation$+$\lnot$$Separation$?  Will $M$ satisfy extensionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the critical point in exactly the same way.

First, note that even though the *cardinalities* of $V$ may not be well-ordered, the *cardinals* and *ordinals* definitely will be. *EDIT: BY "cardinality," I mean cardinality in the most general sense; by "cardinal," I mean cardinality **of a well-orderable set**, that is, "$\aleph$-number." Equivalently, by "cardinal" I mean "ordinal which is not in bijection with any smaller ordinal."*

So we still have the result that $j(\alpha)$ is an ordinal $\ge\alpha$, for every ordinal $\alpha$.

Moreover, by transfinite induction (which doesn't require choice) if $j(\alpha)=\alpha$ for every ordinal $\alpha$ then $j$ is trivial - again, this doesn't use choice.

So the answer is, the critical point can be defined in exactly the same way - as the least ordinal moved by $j$.

Comment: Is this because $V$ and $M$ are well-founded?

Comment: It's more because $V$ *thinks* it is well-founded. By elementarity, $j$ sends ordinals to ordinals. Now, if $j(\alpha)<\alpha$, we must have $j^2(\alpha)<j(\alpha)$, and $j^3(\alpha)<j(\alpha)$, and so forth - and this can be recognized within $V$! So, since $V$ thinks itself well-founded, and $M$ is an inner model of $V$ (so $V$ thinks $M$ is well-founded), we must have $j(\alpha)\ge \alpha$. Similarly, the transfinite induction argument is *internal*, and doesn't depend on $V$ actually being well-founded.

Comment: I generally object treating cardinals as ordinals in ZF. $\aleph$ numbers, $\aleph$ cardinals, can already be used to designate these. But what about cardinal arithmetic? Do you call it "cardinality arithmetic" now?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Personally, I've always found it intuitively clearer to keep the word "cardinal" reserved for specifically well-orderable cardinalities, but I think this exchange indicates that you're right pedagogically. :)

Comment: @Noah: Hah! :-P